# negativeColor and hover state - highchart.js

Tags: highcharts

I would like to use a different hover color state when the value of the column is negative. I wasn't able to find a work-around to accomplish this on highchart.js, but I might be missing something?

I'm currently using `negativeColor` and the `states.hover.color` options.

Here's the reproduction:
https://jsfiddle.net/ceaj8dto/1/

Code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [5, -3, 4, -7, 2]
    }],
    plotOptions: {
            column: {
                negativeColor: 'red',
                states: {
                    hover:{
                        color: 'blue',
                    }
                }
            },
        },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mouseOver` callback function and change color of a point, depending on `y` value.

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        this.graphic.attr({
                            fill: this.y < 0 ? 'black' : 'blue'
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            negativeColor: 'red'
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ctmf2ju/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.events.mouseOver

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!! 
I had no idea about the `this.graphic` method!